# How do I get a token from stripe in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments

```
class PaymentApi {
  final Dio _dio = Dio();

  Future<Response> postAmountApi({
    required PaymentModel payment,
    required String cardNumber,
    required int expMonth,
    required int expYear,
    required String cvc,
  }) async {
    try {
      // Step 1: Obtain Stripe token using a separate function
      String? stripeToken = await getStripeToken(
        cardNumber: cardNumber,
        expMonth: expMonth,
        expYear: expYear,
        cvc: cvc,
      );

      if (stripeToken == null) {
        throw Exception('Failed to obtain Stripe token.');
      }

      // Step 2: Make API call with payment details and Stripe token
      String url = "$apiBaseUrl/v1/payments/pay-with-stripe";
      var token = await getJwt();

      final headers = {
        'accept': '*/*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      };

      Options options = Options(
        headers: headers,
      );

      // Include the Stripe token in the payment model
      payment.stripeToken = stripeToken;

      Response response = await _dio.post(
        url,
        data: payment.toJson(),
        options: options,
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 201) {
        return response;
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to initiate transaction.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}

// Define the getStripeToken function outside the PaymentApi class
Future<String?> getStripeToken({
  required String cardNumber,
  required int expMonth,
  required int expYear,
  required String cvc,
}) async {
  try {
    final PaymentMethod paymentMethod = await Stripe.instance.createPaymentMethod(
      PaymentMethodParams.card(
        number: cardNumber,
        expMonth: expMonth,
        expYear: expYear,
        cvc: cvc,
      ),
    );

    final String? stripeToken = paymentMethod.id;
    return stripeToken;
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error obtaining Stripe token: $e');
    return null;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get a token from stripe, after that I will use that token in my postAmountApi method

I'm getting the following error "The named parameter 'paymentMethodData' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
Try adding the required argument."

what arguments am I supposed to add. If there is an alternative solution I would appreciate as long as I will be able to get the token from stripe

Comment: What actual API/SDK call are you making and getting that error? Note that Stripe does not provide or maintain any Flutter SDK, so you might need to work with the developer of any such plugin you use if this is not a direct API call. Also not that you will want to avoid handling card details yourself and instead leverage secure Elements for collection on the client https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please checkout this code it might help you.

```
 Future<void> generateToken() async {
var userStripeKey = box.read(storeStripeId); //your stripe key
var url = '$BASE_STRIPE_URL$generateToken'; //https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens
var _body = {
  "card[number]": cardNumber.value.replaceAll(' ', ''),
  "card[exp_month]": expiryDate.value.split("/")[0],
  "card[exp_year]": expiryDate.value.split("/")[1],
  "card[cvc]": cvvCode.value,
  "card[name]": cardHolderName.value,
};

var response;
try {
  response = await _dio.post(
    Uri.parse(url),
    headers: headers,
    encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
    body: _body,
  );
  print('GenerateTokenResponse : ${response.body}');
  var cardResponse = json.decode(response.body);
  if (response.body.contains('error')) {
   //handle errors
  } else {
    print('GenerateCustomerToken : ${cardResponse['id']}');
  }
} catch (e) {
  Console.Log('GenerateToken Error', e);
 }
}
```

i hope it will work.